# php bookmarking

Tags: php, html, mysql, bookmarks

I am trying to create an online bookmark system.
I have managed to take the URL from the user and store it to the database. But I want also to take "Title and tags" 
can anyone help me with the code..

```
function add_bm($new_url)
{
  // Add new bookmark to the database

  echo "Attempting to add ".htmlspecialchars($new_url).'<br />';
  $valid_user = $_SESSION['valid_user'];

  $conn = db_connect();

  // check not a repeat bookmark
  $result = $conn->query("select * from bookmark
                         where username='$valid_user' 
                         and bm_URL='$new_url'");
  if ($result && ($result->num_rows>0))
    throw new Exception('Bookmark already exists.');

  // insert the new bookmark
  if (!$conn->query( "insert into bookmark values
                          ('$valid_user', '$new_url')"))
    throw new Exception('Bookmark could not be inserted.'); 

  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to add more columns to your table but hows this:

```
// Add new bookmark to the database
function add_bm($new_url, $new_title, $new_tags){

    echo "Attempting to add ".htmlspecialchars($new_url).'<br />';
    $valid_user = $_SESSION['valid_user'];

    $conn = db_connect();

    // check not a repeat bookmark
    $result = $conn->query("select * from bookmark where username='$valid_user' and bm_URL='$new_url'");
    if ($result && ($result->num_rows>0)){
        throw new Exception('Bookmark already exists.');
    }

    // insert the new bookmark
    if (!$conn->query("insert into bookmark values('$valid_user', '$new_url', '$new_title', '$new_tags')")){
        throw new Exception('Bookmark could not be inserted.');
    }

    return true;

}
```